# Make postgres a synonym of postgresql

Tags: discussion, tagging

Make [postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres) a synonym of [postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

done.

filler to make the answer longer.

Comment: Is that when you follow your own advice? :)

Comment: lol@dezso indeed

Comment: @NickChammas I think I'm an idiot and did this on meta ... lemme try that one more time >.>